# What is the limit of emails sent by an educational facility?

Tags: google-apps-script

Our school (Lane Community College) would like to find out the limits of sending emails to our students. No attachments just simple text messages to maybe less than 2,000 students. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this quotas: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Answer (score 0):

*Depending on the type of account your school has, the limits are the following when using **Apps Script**:*

**Consumer account**

- Email recipients per day - 100* / day;
- Email read/write (excluding send) - 20,000 / day;

**G Suite free edition account**

- Email recipients per day - 100* / day;
- Email read/write (excluding send) - 40,000 / day;

**G Suite Basic account**

- Email recipients per day - 1,500* / day;
- Email read/write (excluding send) - 50,000 / day;

**G Suite Business / Enterprise / Education**

- Email recipients per day - 1,500* / day;
- Email read/write (excluding send) - 50,000 / day;

**Early Access account**

- Email recipients per day - 1,500* / day;
- Email read/write (excluding send) - Flexible

*As for the regular **Email sending limits:***

- Messages per day / Daily sending limit - 2,000 (500 for trial accounts);
- Recipients per message (Addresses in the To, Cc, and Bcc fields of a single email) - 2,000 total per message (maximum of 500 external recipients);

#### Reference

- [Apps Script - Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas);
- [Email Sending Limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en)